# Avoiding multiple load functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I have a 50-item ul. Is there a way to write to not have to write 50 of the below?

```
$(function(){
$("#nav_a").on("click", function(){
    $("#main_text").load("pageA.html #main_text");  
});
$("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
    $("#main_text").load("pageB.html #main_text");  
});    
$("#nav_c").on("click", function(){
    $("#main_text").load("pageC.html #main_text");  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `starts-with` selector `^=` and `split` on the `id` to get the letter:-

```js
$(function() {
  $('[id^="nav_"]').on("click", function() {
    var letter = this.id.split('_')[1];
    $("#main_text").load("page" + letter + ".html #main_text");
  });
});
```

if you want to keep the upper-case then `+ letter.toUpperCase() +`

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to look into split -- seems like something I should learn next.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a common class accross all of these elements like this:

```
<ul class="myElem" data-page="n">...
```

and in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myElem', function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('data-page');  //Get the page
  $('#main_text').load('page' + page + '.html #main_text');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get this one to work. Do I need to do something with the data-page="n"?

I've got code that looks like this:

<li><a id="nav_a" href="#">"I Have Already Told You Everything"</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav_b" href="#">A Bit of the Old Nick</a></li>
    <li><a id="nav_c" href="#">A Decade of Christmas</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the each() and eq() function built in jQuery.
See example:

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var color = ['red', 'blue'];

$("ul").each(function(i) {
  $("ul:eq( " + i + " )").css("color", color[i]);
});
```

And change it for your situation as below:

```
var page = ['pageA.html', 'pageB.html', 'pageC.html'];

$("#nav ul").each(function(i) {
    $("ul:eq( " + i + " )").on( "click", function() {
      $("#main_text").load(page[i] + " #main_text");  
    });
});
```